# Jordan-Brouwer theorem for closed surfaces

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, surfaces

The following is Exercise (6) of Chapter 4 of *Curves and Surfaces*, 2nd edition, by Montiel and Ros, in which the reader is asked to prove the Jordan-Brouwer Theorem for closed surfaces

> **Theorem(Jordan-Brouwer)**: If $S$ is a closed connected surface, then $\Bbb{R}^3 \setminus S$ has exactly two connected components whose common boundary is $S$.

My question is in itens **b** and **c** below. How to prove them?

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

[image]

**EDIT** Why isn't the following a counterexample to **b**?

[image]

Comment: Hint: Where is $B$ in your picture? It should be disjoint from $S$ and contain both $p_2,p_3$.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to take it into account. Thank you very much. I will work with this in mind.

Comment: @MoisheKohan now it makes sense, but I am not able to write down a proper proof. could you help me, please?

Comment: If we let $S=\mathbb{S}^2$ and $B=B_{\varepsilon}(0)$ ($\varepsilon<1$), do the segments inside $B$ cut $S$ transversely? What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, they vacuously do. You can think that they are transverse if they are not tangent

Comment: Even if they do not cut $S$ at all? That's odd

Comment: Yes, but I think only in this way the first item makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, an important observation: Montiel and Ros seem to diverge from the more commonly accepted terminology of "closed manifold" to mean "compact and without boundary". By *closed* they really seem to mean closed in the topological sense, and manifold/surface is already assumed to be boundaryless.

They prove the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem (for closed surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$) assuming compactness, and leave the closed case as an exercise. This is the exercise in the question.

---

With that said, for $(b)$, you can perturb the triangle generated by $p_1,p_2,p_3$ a little in order for it to be transverse to the surface and not change the number of intersections of the lines and the surface. Now, the intersection of such a triangle with the surface is a compact $1$-manifold with boundary and its boundary is precisely the intersections of the lines $[p_1,p_2], [p_2,p_3]$ and $[p_1,p_3]$ with the surface. Of course, $[p_2,p_3]$ does not intersect the surface, so it counts only the intersections of the lines $[p_1,p_2]$ and $[p_1,p_3]$. Since a compact $1$-manifold with boundary is a union of circles and closed intervals, the boundary has an even number of points and the result follows.

For $(c)$, you can pretty much follow the argument he gives for the compact case and define the two sets $A_{even}$ (resp. $A_{odd}$) as the set of points $x$ of $\mathbb{R}^3-S$ such that there exists a segment starting at $x$, ending in $B$ and intersecting $S$ an even (resp. odd) amount of times. Both sets are open by basic facts of transversality, and both sets are disjoint by $(b)$. $A_{even}$ is non-empty since you can pick a point in the ball and have empty intersection. That $A_{odd}$ is non-empty follows from the fact that if you consider a minimum of the function $x \mapsto \lVert x-p_0\rVert$ on the surface  then you just need to extend the segment connecting $p_0$ to the minimum a bit in order to get an element of $A_{odd}$. By the way, such a minimum exists because the minimum of the function restricted to the intersection of the surface with an appropriately large enough closed ball centered on $p_0$, thus a compact set where the existence of the point achieving a minimum is guaranteed, is the same as the minimum of the function on the entire surface.

Now you know that $\mathbb{R}^3-S$ is not connected. Then Proposition $4.4$ in the book concludes what is requested at the end. For reference, the proposition states:

> Let $S$ be a closed connected surface. Then $\mathbb{R}^3-S$ has at most two connected components. Moreover, each connected component of $\mathbb{R}^3-S$ has $S$ as its boundary.

Since the arguments therein are not relevant to the exercise and take up a page, I don't see it being much useful to transfer them here. But this ends the exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention and clearest answer.